# $\arcsin(x) = \arctan(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve this equation for some time now, but have not been able to do it. I know I've been able to solve it before, but I can't remember how.

This is how far I get, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Thank you for your time.
\begin{align}
\arcsin (x) &= \arctan (2x) \\ 
x &= \sin(\arctan (2x)) \\ 
v &= \arctan(2x) \\
x &= \sin(v)
\end{align}

Comment: Draw a triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\tan(\arcsin(x)) = \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\cos(\arcsin(x))} = \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}(\arcsin(x))}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\therefore \arcsin(x) & = \arctan(2x) \Longleftrightarrow \tan(\arcsin(x)) = \tan(\arctan(2x)) \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} = 2x
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

so, if Arcsin(x) = arctan(2x)

then x is the sin of whatever Arcsin(x) is, so therefore the tan of the thing would be

x / sqrt(1 - x^2)

so, we can then drop the arctan

x^ 2 / (1 - x^2) = 4x^2

x^2 = 1 - 1/4 = 3/4

x = sqrt(3/4)

Comment: Are there $\pm$ to consider?

Comment: what do you think?  Go and investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS is defined only for $x\in[-1,1]$ and both functions are odd, hence it is enough to look for solutions in $[0,1]$. $x=0$ is obviously one of them, and there is an extra solution in $(0,1]$, since over such interval both functions are increasing, $\arcsin(x)$ is convex, $\arctan(2x)$ is concave and $\arcsin(1)>\arctan(2)$.
 In order to solve
$$ \tan\arcsin(x) = 2x $$
it is enough to solve
$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 2x $$
or 
$$ \sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2} $$
hence the wanted solutions are $x\in\left\{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right\}$.